# Are Python Multiprocessing Queues Ordered?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Forgive me if this is obvious, but I can't tell from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) whether the output when using a queue is ordered. That is, if the inputs are `[1, 2, 3]` will the outputs be `f(1), f(2), f(3)`, or can they be out of order?

Edit: I understand that the inputs are handled in FIFO. But does FIFO retrieval necessarily guarantee that the results are also returned in order?

Answer (score 10):

No, they will enter the queue in the order they finish, not in the order they were started. This means that if you start your processes with a certain order in mind, they may or may not finish in that order. If order is important to you, you should pass back the starting order with your results in the queue, perhaps as a tuple `queue.put((order, result))`. Here's an example showing the random order you get out of the queue. (Which is still FIFO)

```
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

def square(x, queue):
    # Sleep for a value between 0 and 1. 
    time.sleep(random.random())
    queue.put(x**2)

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

for i in range(10):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target = square, args = (i, queue))
    process.start()

results = []
for i in range(10):
    results.append(queue.get())

print (results)
```

This gave me [25, 16, 9, 0, 36, 64, 81, 1, 49, 4].

Assuming your task is reasonably straight forward, I always prefer using Python's `Pool` functionality and its corresponding `pool.map()` function which does guarantee that output order is preserved according to input order.

Comment: Asker is inquiring for "normal" Queue behaviour meant for multithreading purposes. For this reason Yassine Faris's answer is relevant for this question. But your description of multiprocessing.Queue is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I have a case where I have to replace all `multiprocessing.Queue` into `m.Queue` where `m = multiprocess.Manager()` so that all Queues are ordered. However, I can't reproduce it with a simple example.

I don't really know why but if anyone comes here because their Queue is out of order, I recommend trying this.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as correct. Using queue from manager class makes queue ordered. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

[Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue)

> In a FIFO queue, the first tasks added are the first retrieved
>
> class Queue.Queue(maxsize=0) Constructor for a FIFO queue

Yes, multiprocessing queue are FIFO (first in, first out).

Comment: Does FIFO retrieval necessarily guarantee that the results are also returned in order?

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing queue is never been out of order. From the docs it's clearly mentioned of 3 types. `FIFO`, `LIFO` and priority queue(a way to customize the order). The default order ie. `class Queue.Queue` is using `FIFO`

> In a FIFO queue, the first tasks added are the first retrieved

So considering that,  yes multiprocessing queue maintain the order.

Comment: Everytime i use multiprocessing it executes randomly. For example if each process is supposed to pick an integer from a list of numbers 1 to 10, the execution is all random, thats is, first output could be from 5 , next from 2 etc. I think thats what the question is about

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Queues used by multiple processes get some very unexpected ordering, even with maxsize=1 where you would expect it to run in serial. The official documentation backs up my experimentation:

> If multiple processes are enqueuing objects, it is possible for the
> objects to be received at the other end out-of-order. However, objects
> enqueued by the same process will always be in the expected order with
> respect to each other.

I had the same problem with a manager Queue, once the number of processes accessing it gets higher.

From my experimentation, I've found the best way to manage this is by using `JoinableQueue`, and manually calling `task_done()` at then end of the code that processes the queue get, especially as in my case you are juggling two Queues for input and output. I.e. `JoinableQueue1.get()` - process data - `JoinableQueue2.put()` - then `time.sleep(0.1)` and `JoinableQueue1.task_done()`. You can also better get FIFO from a shared queue used by many processes if you use the `JoinableQueue.join()` method.